# Pythonic way to write attribute which has a random behavior

Tags: python, oop

im writing a code like this

```
import random

class A:  
    def __init__(self):  
        self.att = self.set_att() 
    def set_att(self):
        x = random.randint(0,10)
        if x == 1:
            return "att1"
        elif x == 2:
            return "att2"
        # ... and so on
```

my question is: should i do it like this? or there is a better more pythonic way to do it.
i just want to call set_att in the init.
thank you

pycharm says i should use @staticmethod, but i dont understand is de difference

Comment: I doesn't matter that much. PyCharm is suggesting this to you because your method does not depend on the instance (i.e. on `self`) at all.

Comment: Hint: `{1: 'att1', 2: 'att2', ...}`

Comment: Like @juanpa.arrivillaga suggests, if the number or identity of such attributes can vary (or vary dynamically), then you can back them with an list (/dict) and access them via a random index (/ index into list of dict keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ideas I can think of:

```py
import random

POSSIBLE_ATT_VALUES = [f'att{x}' for x in range(1, 11)]

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        # Produce a one-time random value.
        self.att = random.choice(POSSIBLE_ATT_VALUES)

class B:
    @property
    def att(self):
        # Every access returns a new random value.
        return random.choice(POSSIBLE_ATT_VALUES)
```

```py
>>> a = A()
>>> a.att
"att3"  # Possible value.
>>> a.att
"att3"  # The same value.

>>> b = B()
>>> b.att
"att5"  # Possible value.
>>> b.att
"att1"  # Possibly different value.
```